# Patterns in Python without using lists / only range function

Tags: python

Trying to create the following patterns in Python without using lists and only range function or nested loops.

Patterns are like the following.

```
*******
*  *  *
*  *  *
*******
*  *  *
*  *  *
*******
```

And,

```
**  **
**  **
  **  *
  **  *
**  **
**  **
  **  *
```

A big thanks.

Comment: ...am I the only person who sees blank lines?

Comment: Please look at the preview before posting.

Comment: Should be there now.

Comment: Okay, we've established the problem. But what exactly is your question? SO is not a code writing service. You should consider trying a solution yourself first and then seek help if you get stuck. I didn't downvote you, but this is why you've been downvoted.

Comment: The Python for this challenge is pretty simple.  The hard part is analyzing the pattern to determine which "pixels" are on and which "pixels" are off.  once you have that, a simple nested for y in range: for x in range: with some conditionals will do the job.

Comment: please post some code, or at least the other examples that you found confusing.

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```
print '*******'
print '*  *  *'
print '*  *  *'
print '*******'
print '*  *  *'
print '*  *  *'
print '*******'
```

or

```
>>> for i in range(7):
...     if i==0 or i==3 or i==6:
...         print '*******'
...     else:
...         print '*  *  *'
... 
*******
*  *  *
*  *  *
*******
*  *  *
*  *  *
*******
```

Or there is many way...

Give a more precise question !

Comment: Thanks That helps, I have no idea how to pull this off.

Comment: Try and come back with more specific question, you will find lot of basic tutorial in python

Comment: With your answer I was able to come up with the other one:           for j in range(7):
    if j==0 or j==1 or j==4 or j==5:
        print ('**  **')
    else:
        print ('  **  **')

Comment: Technically, any number of "*" in a row is a list.  A list of characters is still a list.  See my answer for a list free method to solving any pattern, which is probably the purpose of your school project.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to fill 7 x 7 grids with different patterns of asterisks? Cool.  I'll bite.

Let's analyze the first one:

- (0,0) through (0,6) are filled
- (1,0), (1,3), (1,6) are filled
- (2,0), (2,3), (2,6) are filled
- (3,0) through (3,6) are filled
- (4,0), (4,3), (4,6) are filled
- (5,0), (5,3), (5,6) are filled
- (6,0) through (6,6) are filled

If `y` is divisible by 3 (or `y % 3 == 0`), then fill all `x` with `*`
else fill only the `x` that are divisible by 3 (`x % 3 == 0`)

In Python:

```
for y in range(0, 7):
    for x in range(0, 8): # an extra column for newline
        if (x == 7):
            print("\n", end='')
        elif (y % 3 == 0):
            print("*", end='')
        elif (x % 3 == 0):
            print("*", end='')
        else:
            print(" ", end='')
```

Output is:

```
*******
*  *  *
*  *  *
*******
*  *  *
*  *  *
*******
```

Do the same exercise for the second one.

EDIT:

Might as well post the second one:

```
for y in range(0, 7):
    for x in range(0, 8):
        if (x == 7):
            print("\n", end='')
        elif ((x - y) % 4 == 0) or ((x + y) % 4 == 1):
            print("x", end='')
        else:
            print(" ", end='')
```

Results in:

```
xx  xx 
xx  xx 
  xx  x
  xx  x
xx  xx 
xx  xx 
  xx  x
```